# Flutter - Container height same as child height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a child Axis.horizontal ListView.builder under Column -> Container. I want auto height in the Container

```
Column(
            children: [
              Padding(...),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 6,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return brandListLayout('brandList![index]');
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: wrap your container in an expanded widget

Comment: @Brightcode the is horizontal ListView, so i didnot want to my listview wrap my entire screen

Comment: you might have to use a constraintbox in your container with a min and max height for your container

Comment: i didnot ever now what is the min/max height of listview item. it will automatically different by different device

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust ListView's height by different device,
I suggest use 'ScreenUtil' or 'Sizer' package.

- ScreenUtil
  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil
- Sizer
  https://pub.dev/packages/sizer